# How to check an array for an element

Tags: c#, arrays, powershell, null

In the code below, the line

```
foreach (PSObject d in (PSObject[])result.Members["description"].Value)
```

is causing an exception. "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Looking through the debugger, that is because there is no element at ["description"]. How can I check to see if an element is there before attempting to get it?

```
foreach (PSObject result in psInstance.Invoke())
            {
                if (result != null)
                {
                    string pName = result.Members["name"].Value.ToString();
                    string pType = result.Members["parameterValue"].Value.ToString();

                    StringBuilder paramDesc = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach (PSObject d in (PSObject[])result.Members["description"].Value)
                    {
                        paramDesc.Append(d.Members["Text"].Value);
                    }

                    PsAdtParameter param = new PsAdtParameter();
                    param.Description = paramDesc.ToString();
                    param.Name = pName;
                    param.Type = pType;
                    command.Parameters.Add(param);
                }
            }
```

I know how to check for null. But trying this doesn't work:

```
foreach (PSObject d in (PSObject[])result.Members["description"].Value)
{
    if(d != null)
    {
        //Do something
```

Because the reference to Members["description"] causes the exception. Do I have to loop through the array and check each Name property to see if it is "Description"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: That does't work because you have to test if `result.Members["description"]` is `null` before the `foreach`.  And maybe even check if `Value` is `null` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple null check will suffice in that case.  Here are some [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and a good [overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) on the subject.

```
var memberDescription = result.Members["description"] as PSObject[];

if (memberDescription != null && memberDescription.Value != null){
    foreach (PSObject d in memberDescription.Value )
    {
        paramDesc.Append(d.Members["Text"].Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure this will cause the exception as well because it is thrown when accessing the Value-Property of `null`

Comment: You're right. I changed my code to reflect my silly assumption. Ugly to double null check but this should function.

Comment: The cast applies to the `Value`, so now your throwing a cast exception instead.

Comment: Could you explain the cast exception you expect to run into? It should return as null now.

Comment: This is what I ended up using. Thank you. I know this was a basic question that has probably been answered before, but for whatever reason this made sense to me more than other answers I had read.

Comment: in the OP's code `(PSObject[])result.Members["description"].Value` the cast is being applied to `result.Members["description"].Value` not `result.Members["description"]`.

Comment: This makes no sense.  If `result.Members["description"]` is the array of `PSObject` then `memberDescription.Value` will not compile because arrays do not have a `Value` member.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the checks you need to do.

```
if(result.Members["description"] != null)
{
    var psobjects = result.Members["description"].Value as PSObject[];
    if(psobjects != null)
    {
        foreach (PSObject d in psobjects)
        {
            // whatever you want to do with each PSObject
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Either Value was null or it wasn't a PSObject array.
    }
}
else
{
    // whatever you want to do when it's null
}
```

This will additionally make sure that `Value` is an array of `PSObject`.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if it's null first:

```
if ((PSObject[])result.Members["description"] != null)
{
     *** Do whatever ***
}
```

Comment: if performance is a critical thing the result of `(PSObject[])result.Members["description"]` should be stored in a variable before checking and eventually processing it

Comment: I believe the cast actually applies to the `Value`, so this will just throw a cast exception.